Box contains unwanted padding
I'm playing around with compose and am trying to reproduce a twitter profile layout.  It is supposed to look like a profile image sitting at the bottom right of a background image, and a name below.
In order to stack the background and profile image I tried using a Box.  Next to my Box is a Text.  I wrap these in a Column for vertical layout.  Why does my background image display a left and right margin, the box and image use fillMaxWidth()
@OptIn(ExperimentalGlideComposeApi::class)
@Composable
fun TwitterProfile(user: User) {
    Column {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(220.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.header_image),
                contentDescription = "Header Image",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            )
            // needed for padding because GlideImage lacks margin attribute
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(end = 15.dp, top = 130.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.TopEnd
            ) {
                GlideImage(
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    model=user.avatarUrl,
                    contentDescription = selected.fullname,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clip(CircleShape)
                        .size(120.dp)
                        .border(
                            2.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                            CircleShape
                        )
                )

            }
        }
        Text(user.fullname)
    }
}


Did you tried changing contentScale of the Image to ContentScale.FillBounds or ContentScale.FillWidth? Image default contentScale is ContentScale.Fit, it could be the problem. Because regardless of whether you have fillMaxWidth() for the Image, your painter will only fit its container (Image)

Yep, thanks!  I needed a contentScale.

Glad to hear it helped!!

Set contentScale of your Image to FillBounds or FillWidth. Image default contentScale is Fit, so that regardless of whether you set fillMaxWidth() to it, your painter will only fit its container
Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.header_image),
    contentDescription = "Header Image",
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds // Or ContentScale.FillWidth
)

